# how to listen if my arrayList was change?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

How to listen if my ArrayList was changed?
For example if my array have new item or if item was delete.
I use rxjava2 but I don't know if is the good process

```
Observable.fromArray(positionsList())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<ArrayList<LatLng>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(ArrayList<LatLng> list) throws Exception {
                        if (list.isEmpty()) return;
                        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to do? Do you want to be notified if someone calls the `add(...)` or `remove(...)` method on the ArrayList you created? Why are you trying to achieve this by using RxJava? Please provide some more Information.

Comment: Exactly, i want to notifie if one item was add or remove in my list

Comment: If you don't mind it would be great if you could accept my answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

On Android you could use an instance of [`ObservableArrayList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableArrayList.html) and provide it with an implementation of [`OnListChangedCallback`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback.html) that is notified on each change instead of the `ArrayList` you are currently using.

**Sample**

```
public class MyCallback extends ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList> {

    public void onChanged(ObservableList sender) {
        Log.i(tag, "list changed");
    }

    public void onItemRangeChanged(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        Log.i(tag, "item range changed");
    }

    public void onItemRangeInserted(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        Log.i(tag, "item range inserted");
    }

    public void onItemRangeMoved(ObservableList sender, int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount)  {
        Log.i(tag, "item range moved");
    }

    public void onItemRangeRemoved(ObservableList sender, int positionStart, int itemCount)  {
        Log.i(tag, "item range removed");
    }
}


ObservableArrayList list = new ObservableArrayList();
list.addOnListChangedCallback(new MyCallback());
...
list.add(element);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. finally I created my custom listener